# Using an image as the window in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm trying to figure out how to use an image as my window frame. I've been looking at [creating custom windows](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html), but it talks about drawing a custom shape rather than using an existing image.

I want to make a window like this:

[image]

Comment: That Cocoa With Love post tells you how to do what you want -- set whatever you want as the content view of a borderless window. What part are you having difficulty with? Also, did you read the article linked to at the bottom of the post, about `NSThemeFrame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the TunesWindow example by Matt Gemmell:
http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/tuneswindow.tgz 
It uses separate images for the borders, corners and center.

Also checkout MAAttachedWindow by Matt Gemmel:
http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/maattachedwindow.zip 
Panel similar to the one shown in your question.